# How to set view variables from within controller plugin in zf2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have written a controller plugin which passes some variables to my view.
But those variables are not accessible from within my view.

This is the sample code:

```
namespace Application\Controller\Plugin;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class Myclass extends AbstractPlugin
{
    public function setup($event)
    {
        $view = new ViewModel();
        return $view->setVariables(array(
            'MyVariable' => 'VALUE' //this variable is not accessible from within view
        ));

    }   
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please show how you are trying to access the variable in your view.

Comment: just usinng $this->MyVariable

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing your Plugin logic by attaching it to the Event Manager somehow (which it looks like you are, given the `$event` parameter), then you could simply use:

`$viewModel = $event->getViewModel();` and add your variable(s) that way.

Note that this will only work for `MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH` and `MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER` event types because the ViewModel has already been created by the controller action at that point and you're just modifying it. Otherwise, whatever you do here will just be overridden when your action controller fires.

Answer (score -2):

You could attach MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER event and access view model when event trigger:

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
class Myclass extends AbstractPlugin
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        $this->getController()->getEvent()->getApplication()->getEventManager()->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER, array($this, 'onRender'));
    }

    public function onRender($event)
    {
        $viewModel = $event->getViewModel();
        $viewModel->setVariables(array(
            'MyVariable' => 'VALUE'
        ));
    }

}
```